# MS Access vba comma delimited string from field

Tags: string, vba, field

I need short vba code to convert ms access table field to comma delimited string variable

```
T1.F     to    'A','123','008','A'
A
123
008
A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will get your desired string in s :

```
Dim s as String, rs as Recordset

s = " Select [F] from [T1] "
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(s)
s = ""
While Not rs.EOF
    s = s & "'" & rs(0) & "',"
    rs.moveNext
Wend
s = Left(s,Len(s) - 1)
rs.close
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked, but can it be shorter like SPLIT(rs," ',' ") or SPLIT([T1].[F1]," ',' ")?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do something like that to a recordset. I'm pretty sure you'll have to iterate to get the result.